# Vue FullCalendar: Date and Event doubleclick handler

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, double-click

I'm using Vue FullCalendar 5.3.1. I want to add event on doubleclick on empty date cell and edit event on doubleclick on event. How can I implement this? There are 2 methods by default: dateClick() and eventClick() and it's works fine for me.

[image]

My code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <heading class="mb-6">Scheduler</heading>

        <card class="custom-card">
            <FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions"/>
        </card>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
    import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
    import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
    import resourceTimelineDay from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline'

    export default {
        components: {
            FullCalendar // make the <FullCalendar> tag available
        },
        data() {
            return {
                calendarOptions: {
                    dateClick: function(info) {
                        console.log(info.dateStr)
                        console.log(info.resource.id)
                    },
                    eventClick: function(info) {
                        console.log(info)
                    },
                    height: 250,
                    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, resourceTimelineDay ],
                    headerToolbar: {
                        left: 'today prev,next',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek'
                    },
                    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
                    aspectRatio: 1.5,
                    editable: true,
                    resourceAreaColumns: [
                        {
                            field: 'title',
                            headerContent: 'Worker'
                        }
                    ],
                    resources: [
                        {
                            "id": "worker_a",
                            "title": "Worker A"
                        }, {
                            "id": "worker_b",
                            "title": "Worker B",
                            "eventColor": "green"
                        }, {
                            "id": "worker_c",
                            "title": "Worker C",
                            "eventColor": "orange"
                        }
                    ],
                    events: [{
                            "resourceId": "worker_a",
                            "title": "Job 5",
                            "start": "2020-09-15T10:00:00+00:00",
                            "end": "2020-09-15T15:00:00+00:00"
                        }, {
                            "resourceId": "worker_b",
                            "title": "Job 2",
                            "start": "2020-09-15T09:00:00+00:00",
                            "end": "2020-09-15T14:00:00+00:00"
                        }, {
                            "resourceId": "worker_b",
                            "title": "Job 4",
                            "start": "2020-09-15T15:30:00+00:00",
                            "end": "2020-09-15T17:30:00+00:00"
                        },
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

BTW as I noticed that now all calendar settings are passed through `:options = ""`. If you want to pass events like so `<FullCalendar :events="events"/>` or handle an event like `<FullCalendar @dateClick="dateClick"/>`, you cannot do this. Everything needs to be passed in the calendarOptions object ([documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue))

Comment: you'd have to attach your own double-click handlers to the elements in question if you wanted to do that. It's not built in to the calendar. But it works fine with single click, so why change it?

Answer (score 0):

The fullcalendar doesn't provide this option.

But you can attach the double click handler, when the event object is contructed by using an [`Event Render Hooks`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks)

In the version 5 we can use the funcion `eventDidMount`

```
data() {
   return {
      calendarOptions: {
         ...
         eventDidMount: function(eventInfo){
           // Not mandatory, but you can set an id to the object
           eventInfo.el.id = eventInfo.event.id;
           // Set the dbclick event
           eventInfo.el.ondblclick = function(){
               console.log(eventInfo.event)
            };
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Note:** This works, only because this function is called only one time, in case that you are working in other version check how many times the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a work around but you could just count by clicks.

```
onDateSelect(payload) {
  if (this.counter === 1) {
    this.counter = 0
    return this.onDateClick(payload);
  }
  this.counter++
},
```